# Use multiple words in a result search query

Tags: search-results, query

I have made a result query with a few managed properties. We can now search for the metadata columns which works fine. I can't use multiple words in the search for the title column. Here is my query `path: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx RefinableString1: {searchTerms}   OR RefinableString2: {searchTerms} OR RefinableString3: {searchTerms} OR Title: {searchTerms} ContentType:xxx

The result are fine when I use two words for two different managed properties but if a document-set has the title "Salesjob Invoice Red 1150" I can't use two words to fine tune my search in the title. I tried this query but the result is the same.

So how can I use multiple words to search in the Title or in the managed properties?

Found it how i can use more words for the Title, it's "{?Title:{searchboxquery}*} ". Now i can find the content much faster. But i still can't combine the managed properties. For example

path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx {?RefinableString1:{searchboxquery}*} OR {?Title:{searchboxquery}*} ContentType:xxx

I use one word for the title and 1 word for the RefinableString1 but i don't get any result. When i use a single word for the string, the result are fine. I would espect if i use two words for two strings, the result are a combined export.

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like :
`http://mySite/_api/search/query?querytext='((Fred)+OR+(Title:Test*))+AND+(Path:http://bnp-gedoc/Lists/)+OR+(ContentTypeId::0x0101)'&selectproperties='Title,Path,ParentLink,SiteName,DocId'`

Check that your refiner managed properties are mapped to crawled property, in your search schema, in exemple below only RefinableString00 is mapped
[image]

Comment: I tried your solution en i think this should be the query: 

"path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx {?Title:{searchboxquery}*} OR+AND {?RefinableString1:{searchboxquery}*} OR ContentType:xxx"

But i got no result. So i would like to search for a title and for and extra RefinableString1 but it looks i can only use OR in the query instead AND/OR.

Comment: OR Title: {searchTerms} ContentType:xxx,  by defaut, when you use no comparison terme, it will be AND   so => Title: jjjjj AND contentTypdID: xxxx* , so to be sure your query is good use parenthesis, and use search REST Endpoint /_api/search/query?querytext='cccc'&selectproperties='Path'&sortlist='Title:descending'&RowLimit=12 to test your query step by step, do not put all comparison operators to start

Comment: Thank you  for your time. The problem is, how use i Title and RefinableString1 together in one search.  I tried all kind of solutions, with + or = : but all the solutions working for one result. 

site:"https://xxx" {?Title:{searchboxquery}*} OR {?RefinableString1:{searchboxquery}*} ContentType:xxx

This works fine, when i search for a Title or for a string, look my example but i cant use it together now: 
https://imgshare.io/images/2019/11/25/Query.png

Comment: check this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aatishblogs/2014/02/02/refiners-for-managed-metadata-columns-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: (Path:http://llu-sp2016-dev:34436*) AND ((Title:test*) OR (RefinableString00:pages))     is working for me

Comment: Almost there! Thanks for your help, i can now combine the Title and a RefinableString but i have to start with the RefinableString value otherwise i have nog results, very strange. Do you something strange?

(Path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx) AND ((Title:{searchboxquery}*) OR (RefinableString31:{searchboxquery}*)) ContentType:xxx

Example: Stringvalue - title title works perfect
Example: Title title - Stringvalue doenst work

O men, sometime is SP so strange, bleh :(